# How do I use GitHub Version Control with different build Types (Android/Studio)?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

Thank you for reading and any feedback/advice.

I've been developing an android app and have only used one build type until now. I have been using GitHub just to keep a track record of my code while writing it. I only have the master branch at this time.

The app I'm working on is for a family related small business (max 20-30 users) and I have one other person that needs access to the source code. (but is not collaborating). I am nearly complete with my first "module/section" of the app and would like to create a release version apart from continuing working on my code.

Now, I have separated my project into (mainly) two different build types, which I have named: Staging and Release.

My release build is what I'm looking to release for testing to collect some feedback (just 2-3 test users for now). In my staging build I would like to continue developing new additional/features that I am not planning on releasing, yet. I'm trying to keep things pretty simple, as this is not a huge operation.

My question now is:

How should I treat these two build types in regards to my existing repository on GitHub. As stated, so far I've only been committing the whole project under the master branch. My understanding of this is limited. I'm unsure if I will commit the entire project or just build types? I would hope I can commit just a particular build type; and if so would I create a new branch for each build or should either build (staging/release) remain the master and only branch the opposite off?

Thank you!

Edit:

To be more exact, my build Types feature different sourceSets. Like so:

`/src/staging/...`

`/src/release/...`

etc.

My release and staging build Types both have different source Sets. When committing this project, how do I go about making sure only a specific source Sets gets committed to a specific branch? I doubt I should commit both source sets to both branches, right? (I have a feeling I profoundly misunderstand something here)

Comment: Please make sure you’re aware that the version control software is git. Github is a website that hosts them (and has other tools too).

Comment: Okay. I'm aware of that and didn't use proper terminology in the title/post. Sorry. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I’m not trying to punish you for wrong terminology. Many people mix up the two and think github is the vcs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

- Keep Master in staging only.
- For your release create a separate branch from master called `release-v0.0.1`. That way you'll have backward tracking of what you release in what version.
- For releasing you'll have to checkout the `release-v0.0.1`
- For more releases keep on bumping up the minor or major version based on the type of release for example: from `release-v0.0.1` -> `release-v0.0.2` or `release-v0.1.0`
- You can configure your release branch whatever way you want. Also, you'll have this release branch for reference for your future releases.

Edit:

Looking at your edited question I think what you need is build variants, check this out: [Android Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That sounds good so far, but I think I left out an important little fact in my original post. (my build types have different source sets) Therefore I need to expand my question about how to deal with different source sets here.

Comment: Ok, looking at the edited question I think what you need is Build Variants. Check out the link that I gave in the edited response.

Comment: I am using build Variants successfully locally on my device (I can deploy different versions), but I think I have a hard time wrapping my head around how I set my vcs/git up with those properly. Thanks

Comment: If you are using build variants properly then you should not be needing `/src/staging` and '/src/release'. That being said you'll always have only one folder inside src and then you can go with the release branch concept.

Comment: I think I get it. I was wondering because it seemed really tedious and complicated to make sure both of my source sets are properly "versioned" and I became a bit suspicious when I couldn't find *anything* on version control with multiple sourceSets. Because it doesn't make sense I suppose. I just went through the pain of separating my project into these different sources. While I don't know how the branching works exactly, I assume I will revert back to one source set  and just use version control (instead of multiple source sets) to keep different versions of my code...... big oof. Thanks!